# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: sql

I have executed this query on 2 different databases:

**Update table1 set 
PresencePayFactor = cast(30 as decimal (4,2))/ 30**

it is working on one but not on the other.
the 2 databases are sql server 2008 R2

it is giving the following error
"Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric."

What may be the problem?

Comment: have you checked that that column is defined the same way in both databases?

Comment: cast(30 as decimal (4,2))/ 30 equals 1.0

Comment: It is the same database restored on 2 different instances.

Comment: @Boomer - What is the data type of the column?

Comment: but is it a database setting or a query setting, i mean should i set this code before each query executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT set differently between the two?

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
Declare @TestTable Table ( PresencePayFactor decimal(4,2) null )
Insert @TestTable( PresencePayFactor )
Select Cast( 30 As decimal(4,2) ) / 30
GO
-- No error

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON
GO
Declare @TestTable Table ( PresencePayFactor decimal(4,2) null )
Insert @TestTable( PresencePayFactor )
Select Cast( 30 As decimal(4,2) ) / 30
-- Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
```

[SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188791.aspx)

Comment: +1 good call. One of those setting you don't think about usually

Comment: but is it a database setting or a query setting, i mean should i set this code before each query executed?

Comment: @Boomer - Both. You can override it on a query and you can set a default at the database level.

Comment: Hello Thomas.

But i executed this script at a database Lvl and executed a CLR script but was still getting this error.
 It worked only after inserting this script before the execution of my script. anyways it is working now. Thanks again.